# Node.js-Both delete and redirect operations not working from single post request using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, mongodb

I need to delete the rows if corresponding checkboxes are checked.I am using jquery and Ajax to send the selected checkbox ids and deleting.But redirect after delete not working, If i use redirect code in Ajax sucess function, redirecting before the delete operation is preformed.
**Here is my client side code:**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#chkAll").change(function(){
         var status = this.checked;
         $('.chk').each(function(){ 
             this.checked = status;
             });
        });
        $('#sub').click(function(event){
            var  id=$('.chk:checked').map(function(){
                 return $(this).val();
         }).get().join(",")
         $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         data: id,
         url: '/del',
         timeout: 10000,
          success: function (data) {
              if typeof data.redirect == 'string'
                window.location = data.redirect 
        }
     });
     event.preventDefault();
    })
});
```

**serverside code:**

```
router.post('/del', function(req, res, next) {
   var chh=req.body;
   var newchh=JSON.stringify(chh);
    chh=newchh.replace(/:|"|{|}|/g,'');
   var arr=[];
   arr=chh.split(",");

   mongo.connect(url, function(err, db) {
   assert.equal(null, err);
   db.collection('ch').remove({'id1':{'$in':arr}}, function(err, result) {
   assert.equal(null, err);
   console.log(' deleted');
   db.close();

   });
  }); 
  res.redirect('/');
  });
```

Help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send response back to ajax request like this :

```
res.send({status: true, url: "/"});
```

And then in your ajax

```
success: function (data) {
    if(data.status)
        window.location = data.url
}
```

Comment: Glad, it help. :)